# Send DOMElement body to another php

Tags: php, mpdf

I want to generate a Pdf document from a html document. I'm using mPDF class.

My idea was get the body element from html and send it to my pdfgenerator php.
Something like this :

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($_POST['html']);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Question : How can i get the body element via PHP DOM extension from my html and send it to the pdfgenerator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on doing it that way, you could use jQuery (or AJAX) to post the content to your html.

Code written quickly and may not be perfect - please use it as inspiration, not copypasta.

```
var html = $('body').innerHTML();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: /pdfgenerator.php,
  data: data,
  success: success,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

to get the html. Then send it using XMLHttpRequest

```
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://example.com/pdfgeneration.php', true);
httpRequest.send('html=' + encodeURIComponent(html)
```

Comment: I was thinkin in use Php DOM extension, not in Javascript, sry for my error

Answer (score 0):

Create a form with a textarea in javascript and add in in an iframe. Then add a handler onclick so when the button is clicked, javascript adds the body.html (along with `<body></body>` tags if needed to the iframe form textarea and submitted to your other php)

Alternatively you can use Ajax to post the request similarly

Answer (score 0):

use `jquery` to get html and `AJAX` to post html data

```
var html = $('body').innerHTML();
$.post( "pdfgenerator php", {html: html}, function( data ) {

});
```

make sure you add your css files in `pdfgenerator.php`

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($_POST['html'],2);
$mpdf->Output();
```